# Marquee 3000 not going from right to left

Tags: javascript, css, elementor

So I've spent all day on this already. I'm trying to make Marquee 3000 go from right to left. On a section containing icons. The HTML structure looks like this:

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-deb8b11 e-con-full my-ticker-section marquee3k e-flex e-con is-init" data-id="deb8b11" data-element_type="container" data-settings="{&quot;content_width&quot;:&quot;full&quot;,&quot;background_background&quot;:&quot;classic&quot;}" data-marquee3k="" data-speed="1" data-reverse="true">
    <div class="my-ticker-content">
        <div class="my-ticker-item">
            <!-- icon and title for the first item -->
        </div>
        <div class="my-ticker-item">
            <!-- icon and title for the second item -->
        </div>
        <!-- ... and so on for all items -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```js
// Enqueue the Marquee3k script
function enqueue_marquee3k_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('marquee3k', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/marquee3k.min.js', array(), null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_marquee3k_script');

// Add inline script to initialize the Marquee3k library
function add_inline_script_for_marquee() {
    echo '
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            Marquee3k.init();
        });
    </script>
    ';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_inline_script_for_marquee');
```

I am using it in code snippets.

also this is my CSS which I don't think has to do anything with it but whatever:

```css
.my-ticker-item {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px; /* gap between items */
    text-align: center; /* centers the name, icon, and price */
}

.item-name, .item-price {
    display: block;
}

.item-icon img {
    width: 50px; /* adjust as needed */
    height: 50px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

With the following attributes it should go from right to left.
I am using marquee3k.min.js and I am using Elementor page builder.

This is the website wita.cfolks.pl, it's a purple section, can't miss it, it's moving.

I tried adding attributes inside the element which are:

```
data-marquee3k|
data-speed|1
data-reverse|true
```

In elementor Pro

FIX:
Ok for anyone having the same problem, edit the marquee3k.js file and put this code in instead of the original:

```js
/**
 * MARQUEE 3000 MARQUEE 3000 MARQUEE 3000 MARQUEE 3000 MARQUEE 3000
 * http://github.com/ezekielaquino/marquee3000
 * Marquees for the new millennium v1.0
 * MIT License
 */

;(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    root.Marquee3k = factory();
  }
}(this, function() {
  'use strict';

  let animationId = 0;

  class Marquee3k {
    constructor(element, options) {

      if (element.children.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("Encountered a marquee element without children, please supply a wrapper for your content");
      }

      this.element = element;
      this.selector = options.selector;
      this.speed = element.dataset.speed || 0.25;
      this.pausable = element.dataset.pausable === 'true' ? true : false;
      this.reverse = element.dataset.reverse === 'false' ? false : true; // CHANGED HERE
      this.paused = false;
      this.parent = element.parentElement;
      this.parentProps = this.parent.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.content = element.children[0];
      this.innerContent = this.content.innerHTML;
      this.wrapStyles = '';
      this.offset = 0;

      this._setupWrapper();
      this._setupContent();
      this._setupEvents();

      this.wrapper.appendChild(this.content);
      this.element.appendChild(this.wrapper);
    }

    _setupWrapper() {
      this.wrapper = document.createElement('div');
      this.wrapper.classList.add('marquee3k__wrapper');
      this.wrapper.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
    }

    _setupContent() {
      this.content.classList.add(`${this.selector}__copy`);
      this.content.style.display = 'inline-block';
      this.contentWidth = this.content.offsetWidth;

      this.requiredReps = this.contentWidth > this.parentProps.width ? 2 : Math.ceil((this.parentProps.width - this.contentWidth) / this.contentWidth) + 1;

      for (let i = 0; i < this.requiredReps; i++) {
        this._createClone();
      }

      if (!this.reverse) { // CHANGED HERE
        this.offset = this.contentWidth * -1;
      }

      this.element.classList.add('is-init');
    }

    _setupEvents() {
      this.element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        if (this.pausable) this.paused = true;
      });

      this.element.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        if (this.pausable) this.paused = false;
      });
    }

    _createClone() {
      const clone = this.content.cloneNode(true);
      clone.style.display = 'inline-block';
      clone.classList.add(`${this.selector}__copy`);
      this.wrapper.appendChild(clone);
    }

    animate() {
      if (!this.paused) {
        const isScrolled = !this.reverse ? this.offset < 0 : this.offset > this.contentWidth * -1; // CHANGED HERE
        const direction = !this.reverse ? -1 : 1; // CHANGED HERE
        const reset = !this.reverse ? this.contentWidth * -1 : 0; // CHANGED HERE

        if (isScrolled) this.offset -= this.speed * direction;
        else this.offset = reset;

        this.wrapper.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
        this.wrapper.style.transform = `translate(${this.offset}px, 0) translateZ(0)`;
      }
    }

    _refresh() {
      this.contentWidth = this.content.offsetWidth;
    }

    repopulate(difference, isLarger) {
      this.contentWidth = this.content.offsetWidth;

      if (isLarger) {
        const amount = Math.ceil(difference / this.contentWidth) + 1;

        for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
          this._createClone();
        }
      }
    }

    static refresh(index) {
      MARQUEES[index]._refresh();
    }

    static pause(index) {
      MARQUEES[index].paused = true;
    }

    static play(index) {
      MARQUEES[index].paused = false;
    }

    static toggle(index) {
      MARQUEES[index].paused = !MARQUEES[index].paused;
    }

    static refreshAll() {
      for (let i = 0; i < MARQUEES.length; i++) {
        MARQUEES[i]._refresh();
      }
    }

    static pauseAll() {
      for (let i = 0; i < MARQUEES.length; i++) {
        MARQUEES[i].paused = true;
      }
    }

    static playAll() {
      for (let i = 0; i < MARQUEES.length; i++) {
        MARQUEES[i].paused = false;
      }
    }

    static toggleAll() {
      for (let i = 0; i < MARQUEES.length; i++) {
        MARQUEES[i].paused = !MARQUEES[i].paused;
      }
    }

    static init(options = { selector: 'marquee3k' }) {
      if (animationId) window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);

      window.MARQUEES = [];
      const marquees = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.${options.selector}`));
      let previousWidth = window.innerWidth;
      let timer;

      for (let i = 0; i < marquees.length; i++) {
        const marquee = marquees[i];
        const instance = new Marquee3k(marquee, options);
        MARQUEES.push(instance);
      }

      animate();

      function animate() {
        for (let i = 0; i < MARQUEES.length; i++) {
          MARQUEES[i].animate();
        }
        animationId = window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }

      window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          const isLarger = previousWidth < window.innerWidth;
          const difference = window.innerWidth - previousWidth;

          for (let i = 0; i < MARQUEES.length; i++) {
            MARQUEES[i].repopulate(difference, isLarger);
          }

          previousWidth = this.innerWidth;
        }, 250);
      });
    }
  }

  return Marquee3k;

}));
```

Comment: dammit i meant from right to left.

Comment: according to Marquee3000 the default way would be from right to left but when i leave my attributes like this data-speed|1
data-pausable|true. It still goes from left to right. Damn this is just making me crazy

Comment: Please don't add your answer to your question. Instead, add your answer as an answer.